# How flip model upside down?

Tags: transforms, mirror

What I have:
[image: model]

What I want:
[image: model fliped]

Can I get it without playing with rotation degrees? Mirror is not working well for me.

Comment: "*Mirror is not working well for me.*" Why not, what happens when you use it?

Comment: Couldnt you just make the letter "B" then duplicate it, and slide it over slightly. No need to flip anything.

Comment: Use the 3D manipulator widget. Hold CTRL so it snaps to 15' increments.

Comment: Hi @Kitty ! Glad my answer did solve your problem. However I have issue with your last edit of the question. You replaced your original images with those I provided in the answer. Not only do I find this strange, especially without asking or commenting, but this also renders your question useless to others. The transform widget in my screenshots is already in the right orientation. Therefore the **original problem is gone**. Please clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using a custom **transform orientation**.

[image: TO]

With your object selected, tab into Edit Mode. Select an edge that you want to scale along.

For example:

[image: Select edge]

Then, still in Edit Mode, click the [+] symbol under Transform Orientations.

[image: Plus]

This adds the selected edge as a new Orientation.

It is handy to give it a name under the tool shelf on the left side.

[image: Name]

Now you will see this:

[image: new orientation1] and [image: new orientation2]

Finally, select all, hit **S** to scale and then **TWICE** the axis the points in the same direction as the edge you selected and **-1** on your keyboard.

In my case it is the y-Axis.

So I would hit S,y,y,-,1.

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

On the bottom left you'll see:

[image: bottom_left]

Unfortunately, that will mess with your Normals. To solve that, simply hit Ctrl + N. In my case, I had to manually select and flip the Normals inside the B's arcs.

Not a big problem, but if anyone knows how to get around this, please comment.

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

You can apply the rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, which sets the rotation to 0,0,0 without changing your mesh.

1. First rotate your object the way you want
2. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

   This will keep that rotation but reset the rotation co-ordinates to 0,0,0

Comment: Note that this won't actually rotate or flip the model, it will only apply rotation which was already done (if any)